# Typing into input fields on remote computer from android

Tags: windows-10

I have installed Chrome Remote Desktop on Win10 Chrome (and Brave) browsers. Also installed on Android 14. How to type a IRL on the Android so it appears on Win10 browser

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Do you perhaps mean "URL" and not "IRL"? What research have you done? What IS happening, and what is NOT happening when you try this? Does the Chrome Remote Desktop work at all?

Comment: Sorry - meant URL! (Finger conflicts with kbd!) At any rate, problem solved! The CRD kbd did not show up on the Android screen until settings changed. Thank you anyway...

Answer (score 0):

See the Google Support article
[Access another computer with Chrome Remote Desktop](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1649523?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid).

In a nutshell :

- On your computer install Chrome Remote Desktop from
  `remotedesktop.google.com/access`
- Send to Android the one-time code that you get from
  Chrome Remote Desktop via "Generate Code"
- On Android, use menu "Remote Access" to access the computer,
  and enter the code when asked.